# Qué función tiene el método addAttribute de la interface Model en Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza para entender para qué sirve el método addAttribute, cuál es su función. No pude encontrar una explicación detallada, la documentación es muy básica y no termino de entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las clases que implementan la interfaz Model son muy parecidas a un mapa. Le puedes añadir pares claves-valor en las que las claves son strings y los valores cualquier tipo de objeto.

Esta interfaz es utilizada después el motor de plantillas que uses (JSP, Velocity, Thymeleaf, etc.) para sustituir los placeholders que hayas escrito en la plantilla por los valores que tenga el modelo.

Si tienes en tu plantilla o similar algo así:

```
<h1>${titulo}</h1>
```

Y has hecho esto en tu modelo:

```
model.setAttribute("titulo", "Mi título");
```

Cuando se renderice tu plantilla se sustituirá por esto:

```
<h1>Mi título</h1>
```

Comment: Perfecto, creo que entiendo. En este caso concreto qué función estaría cumpliendo?                `@GetMapping("/nueva")                                                                                       
public String nuevaHuerta(Model model) {                       model.addAttribute("huerta", new Huerta());                                                         return "nuevaHuerta";  
 } `

Comment: En ese controlador, inyectas un modelo para poder añadir datos que luego serán sustituidos al generar la vista. Al modelo le has creado un atributo huerta que se entregará a la plantilla que utilices para render ese objeto. Puede que se acceda a alguna propiedad de ese objeto. Por último, retornas el nombre de la plantilla (nuevaHuerta). Esto es lo que le dice a spring qué plantilla tiene que usar para generar la vista. Seguramente tengas un fichero nuevaHuerta.jsp o similar donde esté lo que quieras devolver al cliente.